# Why volume form of compact manifold is not exact?

Tags: differential-geometry

I only know how to use Stoke's theorem to prove this for closed manifold, i.e. compact manifold without boundary. (It is easy, just assume the volume form is exact, and integrate it, by stoke's theorem it is 0, which is impossible)

But how to prove this for compact manifold with boundary. Does stoke's theorem still work? In this case it is not clear for me if the integration over boundary is still 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The volume form of the closed unit interval, $dx$, is exact.

Comment: You are right! I guess for any orientable manifold with boundary the top cohomology is 0 by Lefschetz duality.